# How to perform subset in Sentinel 1 slc data for PSInSAR processing?

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, insar

I want to process sentinel 1 slc dataset for PSInSAR analysis.Currently, I am working on SNAP software and following this [article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWm1W.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWm1W.png): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326655316_ESA_SNAP_-_StaMPS_Integrated_Processing_for_Sentinel-1_Persistent_Scatterer_Interferometry.  and I have made a graph for batch processing.

[image]

How to do subset for my AOI in this process

Answer (score 1):

For me, I usually use the subset operator to crop the AOI at the end.

On the other hand, in the paper you mentioned, there is a process (as shown below).
[image]

In the TOPSAR-Split step, the bursts where the AOI is located can be separated, which can reduce area and the amount of data.
After all the steps are processed, before the export, you can use the subset operator to further crop to get the desired result.